# Running a single stylesheet on multiple input documents and placing all their outputs in a single file

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I am trying to run a single stylesheet on multiple input documents and have their corresponding outputs written to a single output file.

Has anyone done this in XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?

I also have multiple passes in my stylesheet, will this make it trickier to implement?

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you want to achieve. Do you want to run one stylesheet against several input documents but want one result document? Or do you have several stylesheets and want to chain them? There is http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/extensions/output-extras/next-in-chain.xml for this.

Comment: This is exactly what I meant: "Do you want to run one stylesheet against several input documents but want one result document?". I am running one stylesheet on several input documents but I want all their resulting outputs in one output file. Apologize for the confusion.

Comment: Have edited my question to clarify.

Comment: Generally you can process other documents than the primary input document with the XSLT function `document`, the XPath function `doc` and the `collection` function (see http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/sourcedocs/collections.xml). So doing e.g. `<xsl:template match="/"><xsl:apply-templates select="collection('file:///C:/dir/subir?select=*.xml')/node()"/></xsl:template>` would apply the templates in your stylesheet to all child nodes of all `*.xml` documents in that directory. Depending on the stylesheet code that might however not result in well-formed document XML but rather a fragment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends a little on how you want to identify the multiple input documents. If you want to process all the files in a directory, the 2.0 collection() function may be useful (Saxon and probably other processors provide a way of mapping collection() to a filestore directory). Alternatively it's sometimes better to have a master catalogue file, an XML file with links to all the other files, in which case you can supply the catalogue as the primary stylesheet input, and use the doc() function to follow the links.

There's no reason why multiple passes should be difficult. I have one application where the catalogue not only identifies the input files, but also indicates a file type for each file, so that the first transformation depends on the file type, and after that a second standard transformation is applied regardless of the file type. Many variations on such themes are possible.

Answer (score 1):

Just perform all the transformations as part of one single transformation in the wanted order.