# Process Multiple input xml files and generate multiple xml files in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have to pass multiple input xml files and generate multiple xml files as output.

If 'm having 3 files as 'File1.xml', 'File2.xml' and 'File3.xml',
I need to copy the full content of those xml's and also add a node to each xml and then display the output files as 'File1_op.xml', 'File2_op.xml' and 'File3_op.xml'. The output files will have a extra node added like

```
    <Product>45896</Product>
```

I can't pass the file names as static, because it may change. So I need to pass the directory itself and process all the xml files in that particular directory.

Is this possible in xslt? Any help please.

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use? One embedded in a host language as Libxslt in PHP or a standalone like Saxon or just processing through the Browser built-in? Which XSLT Version? Be aware that XSLT itself is independet from it's environment which means it doesn't know anything about the file system. What's available to deal with that depends on the hosting system.

Comment: I'm using XSLT 2.0 , Standalone SAXON

Answer (score 0):

Using Saxon XSLT 2.0 you're on the bright side - I don't have this on hand so I can't give detailled help. My suggestions are
for input file names [Running a single stylesheet on multiple input documents and placing all their outputs in a single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516231/running-a-single-stylesheet-on-multiple-input-documents-and-placing-all-their-ou)
for output [Why does Saxon evaluate the result-document URI to be the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974040/why-does-saxon-evaluate-the-result-document-uri-to-be-the-same)